# show name of the month

Tags: android, eclipse

i am making an app where i have to show the last update from a fitness band, to get the date:

```
SQLiteDatabase sql2 = new SaveDataBase.SaveDateBaseHelp(this).getWritableDatabase();

Cursor select = sql2.rawQuery("SELECT pedometer_year, pedometer_month, pedometer_day from db_pedometer_info WHERE _id = (SELECT _id FROM db_pedometer_info ORDER BY _id DESC LIMIT 1); ", null);

try {
    if(select != null && select.getCount() == 1) {
        select.moveToLast();                
        String year = select.getString(select.getColumnIndex("pedometer_year"));
        String month = select.getString(select.getColumnIndex("pedometer_month"));
        String day = select.getString(select.getColumnIndex("pedometer_day"));                          
        Globals.lastUpdateDate = day + "-" + month + "-" +year;                    
    }
}
```

this show me something like "11-07-2015"
and i want something like this "11-Jul-2015"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] months = new String[] {
    "Jan",
    "Feb",
    "Mar",
    Etc....
};
```

And then when you go to compile the date string instead of just `month` use:

```
months[Integer.valueOf(month)]
```

Comment: when printed appears one months later, how can i rest one ?, im a begginer

Comment: Instead of putting `months[Integer.valueOf(month)]` put `months[Integer.valueOf(month) - 1]`. And don't worry, we all have to start somewhere! Keep it up it pays off :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use SimpleDateFormat to convert a string to a date. Then you can reformat the date the way that you would like it to look.

```
String s = day + "-" + month + "-" +year;
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = format.parse(s);
SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
Globals.lastUpdateDate = dt1.format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method

```
 public String getMonth(String month)
 {
     String [] months = new String[] {
           "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", 
           "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", 
           "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
     for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
         int m = Integer.valueOf(month.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", ""));
         if (m == i) {
             month = months[i - 1];
             return month;
         }
     }
     return "Wrong Month";
 }
```